# Why does global "window" object has multi-level access

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with the window object looking for something. I noticed, the global window object is duplicated into multiple levels.

Try:

```
console.log(window); // returns global window object
console.log(window.window); // returns global window object
console.log(window.window.window); // returns global window object
console.log(window.window.window.window); // returns global window object 
console.log(window.window.window.window.window); // returns global window object

console.log(window === window.window); // returns true
console.log(window.window.window === window.window.window.window); // returns true

window.zombie = "Zombie!";

console.log(window.zombie === window.window.zombie); // returns true
```

Is there any way we can make use of this?

Comment: 0==0  , 0+0==0 , 0+0+0==0 , 0+0+0==0+0 , 0+0+0+0==0+0+0 ,  and also 0+1 == 0+0+0+1 == 0+0+0+0+0+0+1 = ...  :-)

Comment: As per - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window, the window.window returns a reference to the current window. I think now I get the big picture.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really multi-level, you only need one property to point back to itself and you then have recursion.

For example:

```
var zombie = {
    fred: 'Hello'
};

zombie.zombie = zombie;
```

You can now go wild and do:

```
alert(zombie.zombie.zombie.zombie.fred);
```

As to the specifics of why this exists for `window`, see Kevin Brydons answer. It makes sense for the first level but the rest is just a by-product of self referencing.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla have done a concise explanation of the `.window` property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.window

And excerpt :

> The point of having the window property refer to the object itself was
>   (probably) to make it easy to refer to the global object (otherwise
>   you'd have to do a manual var window = this; assignment at the top of
>   your script)

Comment: That's the best answer. +1 for you if you copy here the interesting part of your link

Comment: @dystroy Mozilla's page as a whole gives nairvijays the full answer. I don't see much point in copying the majority of the text. Feel free to edit my answer if you like!

Answer (score 2):

> The point of having the window property refer to the object itself was
>   (probably) to make it easy to refer to the global object (otherwise
>   you'd have to do a manual var window = this; assignment at the top of
>   your script).
>
> Another reason is that without this property you wouldn't be able to
>   write, for example, "window.open('http://google.com/')" - you'd have
>   to just use "open('http://google.com/')" instead.
>
> Yet another reason to use this property is for libraries which wish to
>   offer OOP-versions and non-OOP versions (especially JavaScript
>   modules). If, for example, we refer to "this.window.location.href", a
>   JavaScript module could define a property called "window" inside of a
>   class it defined (since no global "window" variable exists for it by
>   default) which, could be created, for example, after passing in a
>   window object to the module class' constructor.  Thus, "this.window"
>   inside of its functions would refer to that window object. In the
>   non-namespaced version, "this.window" would simply refer back to
>   "window", and also be able to get the document location without
>   trouble. Another advantage is that the objects of such a class (even
>   if the class were defined outside of a module) could change their
>   reference to the window at will, as they would not be able to do if
>   they had hard-coded a reference to "window" (yet the default in the
>   class could still be set as the current window object).

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.window)

Answer (score 1):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window) :

> window.window : Returns a reference to the current window.

This simple reference makes the object cyclic.